# ffmpeg video rotation issue

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, compression

I am using ffmpeg library to compress video and upload it to server.

My problem is : 
Video is saved with perfect rotation in storage but when I upload it to server it gets 90degree rotated.

Command is:

```
setCommand("ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/" + NetworkStatus.OrderNo
            + ".mp4 -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 24 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 96k -s 320x240 /sdcard/videokit/" + NetworkStatus.OrderNo + "out.mp4");
```

Can you please help me to get out of this. I need to show video in portrait mode only if I have captured video in portrait.

Thanks

Comment: So, it shows as portrait in storage and landscape in server? Is it rotated clockwise or anticlockwise?

Comment: We need to see the complete console output/log from your `ffmpeg` command. This will provide important information. What players are you using?